# Existence of periodic solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

> I have the dynamical system
>   $$\left\{ \begin{array}{c l} 
>      \dot{x} &= y\\
>       \dot{y} &= -x-y-y^3  \end{array}\right.$$
>
> And I want to show that there exists no periodic solutions.

Is my reasoning and procedure below correct?

---

The only equilibrium point is $(0,0)$. Using the Lyapunov test function $V(x,y)=x^2/2+y^2/2$ we get that $\dot{V}=-(y^4+y^2) <0 \ \forall \ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}.$ This implies asymptotic stability for the origin. This also means that the positive invariant set for this equation is the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, thus wherever on the plane we start we will eventually go to the origin as $t\rightarrow \infty$. Doesn't this now mean that no periodic orbits/solutions can exists?

I don't really understand why Pioncare-Bendixsons is needed here.

Comment: I observe that $V' = -(y^4+y^2)\leq 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with strict equality if and only if $y\neq 0$, which refines the statement you made in the post.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add $\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. But do you agree that I don't need Pioncare Bendixons here?

Comment: Your edit does not seem to fix the issue: Notice that $(1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ but $$(x(t),y(t))=(1,0) \implies V'(t)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right.

$$
x\dot x = x y\\
y\dot y = -x y - y^2-y^4
$$

adding both equations

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2) = -y^2(1+y^2)
$$

considering that

$$
x = r\cos\theta\\
y = r\sin\theta
$$

we have

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(r^2) = -r^2\sin^2\theta(1+r^2\sin^2\theta)
$$

This represents a kind of spiral sink ($r$ is always decreasing) without periodic solutions

[image]

Comment: I know that I'm right about the non-existence of periodic solutions, but I'm wondering about my motivation for it. I'm sorry If I did not make it clear in my question and thanks for your input!